# Spring cloud config server not loading the properties files

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm trying to use this sample spring cloud config server application https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/configserver but it is not working as expected in my local "windows 7" machine.

When I try to access http://localhost:8888/foo/development I'm getting an result as below without any properties

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "profiles": [
    "development"
   ],
  "label": "master",
  "propertySources": [
  ]
}
```

Below are some of the logs related to the property file loading

> 2015-04-13 17:46:03.381 DEBUG 6684 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.c.s.NativeEnvironmentRepository    : Not adding property source: file:/C:/Users/sekhap/git/configserver/target/config/foo-development.properties
>   2015-04-13 17:46:03.382 DEBUG 6684 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.c.s.NativeEnvironmentRepository    : Not adding property source: file:/C:/Users/sekhap/git/configserver/target/config/foo.properties
>   2015-04-13 17:46:03.382 DEBUG 6684 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.c.s.NativeEnvironmentRepository    : Not adding property source: file:/C:/Users/sekhap/git/configserver/target/config/application.yml

Why the properties not getting loaded? Is there any thing to do with Windows environment and because of "/" in front of the C: ?

Comment: I ran the config-server in Ubuntu and everything works there as expected. This must be a problem in windows only. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922871/i-cannot-see-the-properties-values-using-spring-cloud-config-and-git

Comment: Same issue here in windows, but working fine when running in linux

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the currently released version (1.0.1.RELEASE), and has been fixed in the current snapshot (1.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT).

The code that checks to see if a configuration should be included was not normalizing the file paths, so when running on Windows it failed because the file path had Windows separators ("\") and the path it compares against has linux separators ("/").