# I cannot see the properties/values using spring cloud config and git

Tags: spring-cloud

I am using the sample project 
https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/configserver

I run the project and when i point my browser to 
http://localhost:8888/foo/development/

I get the following values

```html
{
"name": "foo",
"profiles": [
"development"
],
"label": "master",
"propertySources": [
{
"name": "overrides",
"source": {
"eureka.instance.nonSecurePort": "${CF_INSTANCE_PORT:${PORT:${server.port:8080}}}",
"eureka.instance.hostname": "${CF_INSTANCE_IP:localhost}",
"eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone": "http://localhost:8761/eureka/"
}
}
]
}
```

But i do not get the values in the file foo-development.properties in
https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo

I am new to spring-cloud config. Could somebody point in the right direction to the values of the property file ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I ran the config-server in Ubuntu and everything works there as expected. This must be a problem in windows only. The output I get in Ubuntu is the following:

```
{
"name": "foo",
"profiles": [
"development"
],
"label": "master",
"propertySources": [
{
"name": "overrides",
"source": {
"eureka.instance.nonSecurePort": "${CF_INSTANCE_PORT:${PORT:${server.port:8080}}}",
"eureka.instance.hostname": "${CF_INSTANCE_IP:localhost}",
"eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone": "http://localhost:8761/eureka/"
}
},
{
"name": "https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo/foo-development.properties",
"source": {
"bar": "spam"
}
},
{
"name": "https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo/foo.properties",
"source": {
"foo": "bar"
}
},
{
"name": "https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo/application.yml",
"source": {
"info.description": "Spring Cloud Samples",
"info.url": "https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples",
"eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone": "http://user:${eureka.password:}@localhost:8761/eureka/",
"invalid.eureka.password": "<n/a>"
}
}
]
}
```