# Config server with git repository does not work well

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have my private git repository created with gogs and running into docker containter.
When I start my config server, a temporal folder is created in my personal folder with a name like these: **config-repo-6084055946640576163** 
Inside it, apears all the config file, so I asume that the repository is cloned by the server, but, when I access it through the internet explorer I can`t see the config, they are empty.

I chedk that url http://localhost:8888/micro-central-get-ticket/env
and I get

> {"name":"micro-central-get-ticket","profiles":["env"],"label":"master","propertySources":[]}

My server config file looks like:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: server-config
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:3000/admin123/config-repository
          password: admin123
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You shouldn't use `/env` try `/master`.

Comment: I get {"name":"micro-central-get-ticket","profiles":["master"],"label":"master","propertySources":[]}

Comment: Looks like you aren't getting the properties but something else. You didn't change the context root?

Comment: If I read the config files from my classpath it works.

Comment: ? Why would the files be on the classpath, they are in the config-server not on the classpath of the services using the config-server...

Comment: I move that files to a git, they were in the classpath just for testing, so I know that they was visitble thwough server config, but now, inside my git repository I can see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems something releated to windows, deploying the application on linux worked.
Check that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605520/spring-cloud-config-server-not-loading-the-properties-files)